# ExtentReports & AndroidDriver doesn't produce screenshots inside the report

Tags: java, android, selenium, screenshot, appium

I'm facing a problem where I can't properly add a screenshot to my **ExtentReport** report, instead, small image icon appears. I've tried many options (absolute path vs relative path); nothing works. My question is: because I'm running my selenium scripts on mobile devices (in this case Samsung Glaaxy Tab 4) may be Extent Reports library doesn't support that. Below is my script example and a screenshot that I'm getting:

```
[public class Whatever {
WebDriver driver;     
ExtentReports report;
Date date;

@Test
public void testOFWhatEver() throws Exception {

ExtentReports report = new ExtentReports("C:\\XXX\\XXX\\AppiumScreenshots\\SamsungGalaxyTab4TestResults\\" + "report" + ".html");
ExtentTest test = report.startTest("Home Page UI test", "Verification that all elements on the Home Page locate correctly");
Some code;
Some code;
Some code;
test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Snapshot below:" + test.addScreenCapture("/SamsungGalaxyTab4TestResults/01.png"));
report.endTest(test);
 report.flush();][1]
```

Comment: Is the image saved in the correct location?  Are u using correct locatuon to link image on the report ?  I am not seeing how you are saving the snapshot..  Most issues I follow from github are due to invalid path.

Comment: As Karthik said. It is most likely issue due to your path.
Either use full path or add "../SamsungGalaxyTab4TestResults/01.png".
The same solution works on my end.